# overwrite first n lines of a file

Tags: files

I have a 7gb text file
I need to edit n first lines of that file (let us assume n=50)
I want to do this the following way:

```
head -n 50 myfile >> tmp
vim tmp # make necessary edits
substitute first 50 lines of myfile with the contents of tmp
rm tmp
```

how do I complete the third step here? better solutions to the general problem are also appreciated
note: there is no GUI in this environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`man tail` says:

```
   -n, --lines=[+]NUM
          output the last NUM lines, instead of the last 10;
          or use -n +NUM to output starting with line NUM
```

therefore you can do

```
tail -n +51 myfile >>tmp
```

Comment: you are right in that the additional `result` file is redundant. however in comments to another answer we figured out that some systems' implementations of `tail` command treat the `-n` argument differently

Comment: nevermind that - i forgot about the `+` modifier which indeed suffers from the 0-fallacy

Answer (score -1):

Make a backup

```
cp fileorig.txt fileold.txt
```

copy 50 lines in tmp.txt

```
head -n 50 fileorig.txt > tmp.txt
```

make necessary edits with vim

```
vim tmp.txt
```

To make the 3d thing do this

First remove the first 50 lines with sed

```
sed -i 1,50d fileorig.txt
```

then cat tmp edited+fileorig.txt in newfile

```
cat tmp.txt fileorig.txt > filenew.txt
```

See filenew.txt if you like it
if something go wrong restore
bacckup

```
cp fileold.txt fileorig.txt
```

Comment: thank you. i'm unsure all the precautions are really necessary, though - copying a 7gb file sounds like a lot. what do you think?

Comment: Better wait to copyng than lost forever a file

Comment: true. but how exactly can you lose a file this way?

Comment: For example a bad command,wrong typing with keyboard,loss of power when file is writed

Answer (score -1):

found a solution

```
head -n 50 myfile > tmp
vim tmp # make necessary edits
cat tmp > result
tail -n 50 myfile >> result
# result now contains the edited myfile
```

Comment: you probably need `+51` instead of `50` in your tail command.

Comment: no. i just checked it - `tail` negates first n lines

Comment: In that case it probably depends on the `tail` command provided by your system. At least gnu tail will start with the 50th line.

Comment: interesting, thank you! will keep that in mind

Comment: What OS do you work on? What version of tail is installed? (Does `tail --version` give a hint?)

Comment: it does not. i run osx elcapitan